# Am I using the simple interest formula correctly?

Tags: finance

*Sally has inherited a land that was purchased for $30,000 in 1960. The value of the land increased by approximately 5% per year. What is the approximate value of the land in the year 2017?*

The answer is $484,000.

I tried using the simple interest formula $I = Prt$ to solve this problem. But I get $$I = 30,000*0.05*57 = $85500$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should use $30000 \cdot (1.05)^{57}$

Comment: this is equivalent to compound interest, because its 5 percent increase from the previous year every year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be compound interest, not simple interest.

$30000 \times (1.05)^{57} \approx 484073$

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are meant to use compound interest for this. Simple interest does not make much sense for explaining the increase in value of an investment over such a long period of time.

Compounding investment returns is such a common assumption that whoever posed the problem probably thought it was not necessary to mention it.